# How to add image background from props in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs

I am building a website using reactjs. I have a js file which extract props from another file which is an array called `sections` with data like `title` and `imageurl`. I need to use the prop of `imageuURL` as a background for each element. I tried to use style but it doesn't work.

Here is the code of extracting :

```
import React from 'react'

const Menuitem = (props) => {
    return(
        <div>
            <h1 className='title'>{props.title}</h1>
            <span className='subtitle'>shop now</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I pass that code through array in app.js using the following function:

```
function extract(item) {
  return <Menuitem title={item.title}/>
}
```

Then use map function to return result

```
  function App() {
      return (
          <div className=''>
              {sections.map(extract) }
          </div>
      );
  }
```

The result I get is like the image. I need to get a background image for each section from the array file
( imageURl prop )

[react js problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkBMs.png)

Comment: Your codes aren't clear enough to see your issue. Please reproduce your codes with online editors (code sandbox, jsfiddle, ..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the imageURL is inside the props passed to the menu item you can just put it in inline

```
const Menuitem = (props) => {
    return(
        <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.imageUrl})` }}>
            <h1 className='title'>{props.title}</h1>
            <span className='subtitle'>shop now</span>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: thanks i tried it before it didn't work . the only difference that you added some spaces . is it a must ??